# Identifiying the next point on the surface of a cube ( or 3D object )

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, 3d, surfaces, parametric

I have a cube of unit length. Each face of the cube is divided into 10 x 10  equal segments. Consider an object of size equal to that of a segment moving through the surface of the cube ( or any 3D object ).

I need to mathematically compute an equation through which I can get the next segment in the cube given the direction of the object.

EDIT:

I agree with the comments that this problem can be approached progammatically. I was looking for a way to do it in a generic way ( maybe like a parametric surface ) where you specify a domain (u, v) and a range of values (x,y,z) for a 3D Object.

An example would be like this - http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001814/ch03.html#ch03_id36001767 . Can we define one such mathematical function for a cube?

To put in simple words, can a function be defined for the domain f(u, v) which will give a range of (x, y, z) values for a cube?

Comment: The next segment over which the object will fit perfectly? Or the next segment it touvhes? Please illudtrate your problem and we might be able to help you.

Comment: Have a look at this Snake game in 3D - http://www.springfrog.com/games/snake/3d-cube/ ( Actually I was learning to do something like this.)

Comment: that game makes me a little dizzy....  But in all seriousness, try cleaning up your post; its not clear what you want. We'd love to help though

Comment: The equation shoud depend on how you decribe a snake position in the game. Can you add this decribtion to your question?

Comment: This isn't a mathematical question, so you could have asked on stackoverflow or somewhere else. Anyway as Alex pointed out it depends on how you want to store the snake position. The most trivial way would be to store the 3 coordinates of the snake, and after moving the snake checking all cases where the snake moved off the cube, one for each edge, and reflect the snake back onto the cube, which would be one line of code per case.

Comment: "Each face of the cube is divided into 10 x 10 segments." What does this even mean? Are the segments of equal size, for example?

Comment: @Squirtle Please check the link that I have posted in the comments above.

Comment: I checked the post.... actually when you asked this question about a month ago.  Its your English I don't understand, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The game of Snake in $3$D is really just a game of Snake in $2$D with slightly different boundary conditions on the box. One can unfold a cube like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3lEO.png). On the inner squares, the place that the snake will go next is obvious, it's the same as it would be for the $2$D case. However, at the edge squares of the cube, you'll just have to look at the sides and see which ones correspond to which; I've drawn some examples there for reference. This is for the case of a $2\times 2$ grid, but it should be easy to generalize to $10\times 10$.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should really be moved to stack overflow. At any rate, as one of the commenters mentioned, how you do this really depends on how you store the position of the object. You could just store the coordinate position inside the object and increment the coordinate in the correct direction...